Is it possible to create an event in a Kotlin class and listen to it in NativeScript Core (JavaScript)?
I am developing an APP in NativeScript(Javascript) which consumes a Kotlin class.
I would like to receive events from Kotlin to treat them in NativeScript.
The Kotlin class calls other packages in Kotlin and Java. Executes many operations, and dispatches events.
Thanks
//parent.js

const application = require("@nativescript/core");
const ctx = application.android.context;

helloKotlin = new com.example.HelloKotlin(ctx);

helloKotlin.on()

helloKotlin.fetchFiles()


// HelloKotlin.kt
package com.example

import android.content.Context
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope

class HelloKotlin(context: Context): ViewModel() {

  fun fetch() {
    // fetch file1
    // dispatch an event: "File 1 - OK!"

    // fetch file2
    // dispatch an event: "File 2 - OK!"

    // fetch file3
    // dispatch an event: "File 3 - OK!"
  }


}```






I found a lot of examples on how to do this from Kotlin to Kotlin and Kotlin to Java, but none on Kotlin to NativeScript.

